i ran my react project using npm start and it displayed upgrade required on the browser instead of the home page
Problems loading reference 'https://json.schemastore.org/package': Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/package': getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND json.schemastore.org.
(this showed in the terminal as a problem)
:3001/favicon.ico:1
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 426 (Upgrade Required)

localhost/:1
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 426 (Upgrade Required)

(this showed in the console)
